# mongoengine update listfield of embedded document

Tags: python, django, django-views, mongoengine

I am trying to update a listfield of embedded documents in mongoengine. I have gone through almost all the related questions but somehow my code just won't work. I know there is something small that I'm missing but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code :

Documents:

```
class Address(EmbeddedDocument):
    line1 = StringField(required=True, max_length=63)
    line2 = StringField(max_length=127)
    pin = StringField(max_length=6, min_length=6)


class Store(EmbeddedDocument):
    code = StringField(max_length=50, required=True)
    store_name = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    address = EmbeddedDocumentField(Address)


class Vendor(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    stores = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Store))
```

View:

```
def stores(request, *args, **kwargs):
    .......
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            if request.POST.get('oper') == 'edit':
                post_dict = request.POST
                # updated_vendor = Vendor.objects(pk=vendor_pk, stores__$__)
                vendor.update_store(vendor_pk, post_dict)
                return get_json_response({'msg': 'Store details updated successfully!!'})
        else:
            ....

def update_store(self, vendor_pk, post_dict):
        print post_dict
        store = [attr for attr in self.stores if attr.code == post_dict.get('code') and attr.store_name == post_dict.get('store_name')]
        vendor = self
        new_address = Address(line1=post_dict.get('line1'), line2=post_dict.get('line2'),
                              city=post_dict.get('city'), state=post_dict.get('state'),
                              country=post_dict.get('country'))
        if post_dict.get('pin') != 'None':
            new_address.pin = post_dict.get('pin')
        print "address new", new_address.line2, new_address.pin
        new_store = Store(code=post_dict.get('code'), store_name=post_dict.get('store_name'), address=new_address)
        print "new store", new_store.address.line2, new_store.address.pin
        if store:
            index = vendor.stores.index(store[0])
            updated = Vendor.objects(pk=vendor_pk, stores__code=post_dict.get('code'), stores__name=post_dict.get('store_name')).update_one(set__stores__index=new_store)
            print "updated", updated
            #print index,vendor.stores[index].address.city
            # del vendor.stores[index]
            # vendor.stores.append(new_store)
            # vendor.stores[index].code = post_dict.get('code')
            # vendor.stores[index].store_name = post_dict.get('store_name')
            # vendor.stores[index].address.line1 = post_dict.get('line1')
            # vendor.stores[index].address.line2 = post_dict.get('line2')
            # if post_dict['pin'] != 'None':
            #     vendor.stores[index].address.pin = post_dict.get('pin')
            # vendor.save()
```

These are my print statements' output :

```
<QueryDict: {u'oper': [u'edit'], u'code': [u'BSK'], u'pin': [u'1'], u'line2': [u'near huda city center'], u'line1': [u'Shushant Lok'], u'store_name': [u'Baskin'], u'id': [u'2']}>

address new near huda city center 1

new store near huda city center 1
updated 0
```

My update_store method just won't work. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I got my code to work now.
I modified my update_store method to this and it worked.

```
def update_store(self, post_dict):
        vendor = self
        new_address = Address(line1=post_dict.get('line1'), line2=post_dict.get('line2'))
        if post_dict.get('pin') != 'None':
            new_address.pin = post_dict.get('pin')
        new_store = Store(code=post_dict.get('code'), store_name=post_dict.get('store_name'), address=new_address)
        index = int(post_dict.get('id')) -1
        stores = vendor.get_active_stores()
        stores[index].is_active = False
        vendor.stores.append(new_store)
        vendor.save()
```